# Errors using brew to install python3

Tags: macos, install, homebrew, python

I'm trying to install *python3* using *brew* on a 2008 MacBook (OSX Lion).

I have a few years using *apt-get* in Linux environments, but this is my first time trying to install something using *brew*.

Per the instructions at [Get Your Mac Ready For Python Programming](http://www.pyladies.com/blog/Get-Your-Mac-Ready-for-Python-Programming/) and [Install Python 3 on Mac OS X and use virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/07/install-python3-on-mac-os-x-and-use-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper.html) I entered:

```
brew install python3
```

This was after accidentally trying to install version 2.x of python using

```
brew install python
```

The *python* package installs fine, but when trying to install *python3* I get

```
gcc-6 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g  -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -o FileSettings.o -c ./FileSettings.m
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:120:0,
             from ./FileSettings.h:9,
             from ./FileSettings.m:9:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSTask.h:75:24: error: expected identifier or '(' before '^' token 
 @property (copy) void (^terminationHandler)(NSTask *) NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, NA);
                        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSTask.h:78:1: error: expected identifier before 'end'
 @end
 ^
make[2]: *** [FileSettings.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install_PythonLauncher] Error 2
make: *** [frameworkinstallapps] Error 2

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues

These open issues may also help:
python & python3: fix sqlite3 on sierra https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/3134
Warning: You are using OS X 10.7.
```

Per the errors I checked [python & python3: fix sqlite3 on sierra](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/3134) which seems to indicate the fault lies somewhere with *sqlite3* however the link at [python3 (v 3.5.1) failed to build on 10.7.5-x86_64](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/47578) indicates its an issue with the compiler?

I'm not sure where to go next in the troubleshooting process.

Comment: Which version of OSX?

Comment: Have you tried using the Anaconda distribution of Python 3? It's a very nice package from https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos,

Answer (score 1):

I have no way to test it as I am not running 10.7 anymore, but the second issue you [posted](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/47578) looks like the exact same error and a successful fix was in the comments:

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/apple-gcc42
brew install python3 --cc=gcc-4.2
```

This basically installs a compatible version of gcc and overrides compiler selection when installing python3.